# Getting error .append is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split up a string on /* and then to split up those segments on */

So that I can separate out all of the comments as **I want this code to be able to take all of the comments out of the string and then put it back together.**

The problem is though I keep getting this `.append` error which I am pretty sure is because I have made a silly syntax error but I am struggling to find it and any help would be greatly appreciated.

**JS**

```js
contents = "if for /* else */ . = == === /* return */ function"

var start = /\/\*/gi;
var end = /\*\//gi;
var commentsRemovedSec2 = [];

var commentsRemovedSec1 = contents.split(start);
console.log(commentsRemovedSec1);

for (var i = 0; i < commentsRemovedSec1.length; i++) {
  var z = ""
  var x = commentsRemovedSec1[i]
  var y = x.split(start)
  z = y[0]
  commentsRemovedSec2.append(z);
};

console.log(commentsRemovedSec2);
```

Comment: Append isn't an array method. However `myArray.push(newItem)` is

Comment: As @evolutionxbox mentioned use   commentsRemovedSec2.push(z); instead of append.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unfortunately `.append()` isn't an Array method.

Instead use the Array method [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```
commentsRemovedSec2.push(z)
```

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
>   returns the new length of the array. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)